# Changing text of TextView -- old text doesn't go away (Android 4.1.2)

Tags: android, textview

I'm pretty new to Android development. Trying to accomplish something fairly simple -- change some displayed text when a timer ticks. Here's the potentially relevant code:

```
CountDownTimer currentTimer;
Resources res;
TextView timerText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_exercise);
    res = getResources();

    timerText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer_text);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    //"Get ready" countdown
    currentTimer = new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            timerText.setText("" + (int)Math.ceil(millisUntilFinished / 1000.0));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            ...
        }
    };

    currentTimer.start();
}
```

This works fine on an emulated 4.2.2 device, but on a 4.1.2 device (both physical and emulated), the changed TextView appears as such while the countdown proceeds:

[image: Changed TextView]

If you can't tell, that's the numbers 5,4,3 overlayed. So, when I set a new string for the TextView, the new string is displayed but without replacing the old string. Any other TextViews used in my app behave in the same way.

Any ideas what the problem is and how to fix it?

**Edit**: From the XML layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".ExerciseActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    ...

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timer_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:hint="@string/timer_default" />

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

That's all that could be relevant.

Comment: Be sure that you change the text in the UI Thread. In what Thread is `onTick()` running?

Comment: Post your layout XML file.

Comment: try `timerText.invalidate();` after setting the text.

Comment: Not sure what thread onTick was running on, but I've tried the code from Martin's answer to run it on the UI thread and nothing changed. Invalidating the TextView also did not help. I'll add the XML to my question.

Comment: Which text does the "hint" attribute contains?????

Comment: @string/timer_default is just the string "00".

Answer (score 0):

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
TextView timerText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    timerText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer_text);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    CountDownTimer currentTimer = new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            timerText.setText("" + (int) Math.ceil(millisUntilFinished / 1000.0));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
        }
    };

    currentTimer.start();
}
```

}

Tested on 4.1.2 Emulator and solved.

My guess is that the final reference variable is causing the problem.

Comment: Thank you, but strangely the problem persists for me. I made currentTimer local and pulled out the scope of timerText, as well as adding @Override to the timer methods, as in your code, but no dice.

Answer (score 0):

**Temporary solution:**
You should set background for LinearLayout: android:background="@color/white".
I'm looking for the cause.